# Why chmod 777 not permitted on a rwxrwxrwx file?

Tags: linux, permissions, file-permissions, chmod

I have a folder with `777` access, `foo` user belongs the `pi` group, but I cannot change the permissions on `foobar`. What is the explanation?

```
$ sudo usermod -a -G pi foo
$ sudo -u foo touch foobar
$ ls -al
total 0
drwxrwxrwx 2 pi pi 0 Feb 27 19:26 .
drwxrwxrwx 6 pi pi 0 Feb 26 15:20 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 pi pi 0 Feb 27 19:26 foobar
$ sudo -u foo chmod 777 foobar
chmod: changing permissions of ‘foobar’: Operation not permitted
```

It is worth mentioning that the mount is:

```
//192.168.1.42/test /media/test/ cifs username=pi,password=p,uid=pi,gid=pi,x-systemd.automount 0 0
```

**EDIT**

[codeforester](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6862601/codeforester) reminded me that `foobar` is owned by `pi` so `foo` cannot change the permissions on it. So the issue is more a [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/) where:

I mounted `/media/test/` with the generic `pi` user and group. Daemon users such as `foo` and `bar` will require access to this shared folder in `rw` and they should be able to change the permissions. How can I do it?

Comment: The foobar file is owned by `pi` and `foo` cant change permissions on it.

Comment: But foo created the file, so why is it owned by pi?

Comment: Looks like it was there before. `touch` will silently "ignore" an existing file. For the permission thingy, check `man 2 chmod` in addition to `man chmod`.

Answer (score -1):

Simplest solution I think is to add foo and bar to pi user group

## usermod -G pi foo